# Syntax error unexpected ON

Tags: mysql

```
DELIMITER $$
SET TERMOUT ON
PROMPT Building Tutorial System. Please wait.
-- SET TERMOUT OFF


-- Drop Tables
DROP TABLE Enrollment CASCADE CONSTRAINTS;
DROP TABLE Attendance;
DROP TABLE Student CASCADE CONSTRAINTS;
DROP TABLE Tutorial CASCADE CONSTRAINTS;

-- Create Tables
CREATE TABLE Student(
    id NUMBER(10) PRIMARY KEY NOT NULL,
    name VARCHAR(255)
);
CREATE TABLE Tutorial(
    id NUMBER(10) PRIMARY KEY NOT NULL,
    name VARCHAR(255),
    tutor VARCHAR(255),
    room VARCHAR(255),
    day NUMBER(10),
    time DATE,
    end_date_of_tutorial DATE,
    type NUMBER(1)
);
CREATE TABLE Enrollment(
    id NUMBER(10) PRIMARY KEY NOT NULL,
    student_id NUMBER(10),
    tutorial_id NUMBER(10),
    enrollment_date_of_tutorial DATE,
    FOREIGN KEY(student_id) REFERENCES Student(id),
    FOREIGN KEY(tutorial_id) REFERENCES Tutorial(id)
);
CREATE TABLE Attendance(
    enrollment_id NUMBER(10),
    att_date DATE, 
    attendance CHAR(1),
    FOREIGN KEY(enrollment_id) REFERENCES Enrollment(id)
);
```

I am getting red errors marks in MySQL workbench source code editor on line 1 "SET TERMOUT ON" Syntax error unexpected ON been trying to resolve this issue however no progress so if someone could help me out.

Answer (score 1):

First of all, the correct `SET` syntax is

```
SET var = value
```

See http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/set-statement.html

Also, with the `SET` command you can either change a system variable or initialize a user variable. AFAIK `TERMOUT` is not a system variable so you should use:

```
SET @TERMOUT = ON
```

Finally, I am not sure that "ON" is a valid value for a user variable so you probably should use

```
SET @TERMOUT = 1
```